# Laravel push lot of data to Queue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model with ~500k records in the database. I need to get all items and push ~500k jobs to the queue.

I tried:

```
Model::cursor()->each(function ($item) {
    dispatch(new Job($item));
});
// and
Model::chunk(10000, function ($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        dispatch(new Job($item));
    }
});
```

But in both cases I got a memory leak because I need iterate all 500k records and call `dispatch()` method in any case. Is there best way to push a lot amount of data to the Laravel queue?

Answer (score 0):

Working only with ids may work in your case. Give a try.

**Dispatching**

```php
Model::select('id')
      ->get()
      ->pluck('id')
      ->each(function ($id) {
          Job::dispatch($id);
      });
```

**Job**

```php
class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, Queueable, InteractsWithQueue;

    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $item = Model::find($this->id);
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better, thank you. But I still got a memory leak, I think I should break this huge result into chunks and use something like job batching...